# Does using sigwait and signalfd concurrently in a multithreaded program result in a race condition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, race-condition

I am writing a multi-threaded program where, among other things, I have a thread listening to a socket for incoming network connections. To allow this to be interrupted, I am using `poll` in combination with `signalfd` (rather than a raw `await` call). However, I also have other threads that I need to be able to notify of potential interrupts, so I am using a `sigwait` call in a dedicated thread to wait for signals. My attempt to get the race to occur is in the code below:

```c
int main()
{
    int sigval = 0;

    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset (&mask);
    sigaddset (&mask, SIGINT);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr);
    
    int sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, SFD_NONBLOCK);

    auto handler = std::thread([&] {
        int signal;
        sigwait(&mask, &signal);
        sigval = signal;
    });

    pollfd pfd[1] = {{.fd=sfd, .events=POLLIN}};

    int ret = poll(pfd, 1, -1);

    std::cout << "Poll returned with revents = " << pfd[0].revents << std::endl;

    handler.join();
    
    std::cout << "Handled thread set sigval to: " << sigval << std::endl;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Every time I run this and kill it with `SIGINT`, it appears to work, in that the `poll` call returns, and `sigval` is set by the handler thread. However, my understanding is that `sigwait` consumes the signal, while `signalfd` does not. So, if somehow `sigwait` was called before `signalfd` received notification of the signal, this program could potentially hang forever (with poll waiting for a signal that isn't coming). I assume since I can't manage to get the program to hang that there is something on beneath the hood that prevents this from happening, but can I guarantee that this will always be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the linux source code, and have come up with an answer to my own question: there is no race condition, as the signalfd watchers are explicitly notified *before* the signal is sent, so they will always be notified before the signal is sent (and caught). Specifically, in `linux/kernel/signal.c`, we see:

```c
out_set:
    signalfd_notify(t, sig); // <-- signalfd notified
    sigaddset(&pending->signal, sig);
    ...
    complete_signal(sig, t, type); // <-- sends the signal
```

so it is not possible for `sigwait` to consume the signal before `signalfd` is notified about the signal.